# VB.net copy table from 1 database (ODBC) to another (Access) without using select into

Tags: database, vb.net, copy

I am using VB.Net and need to copy 9 tables from an ODBC connection (Gupta database) to an Access database.
I can not use the sql statement SELECT INTO..... as the odbc connection doesn't support this.
In vb6 I have used:

```
 Set rsCopierenTabel = New Recordset
    sqlCopierenTabel = "SELECT * FROM " & tblTabel
    rsCopierenTabel.Open sqlCopierenTabel, conUnit4, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    If rsCopierenTabel.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rsCopierenTabel.MoveFirst

        Set rsPlakkenTabel = New Recordset
        sqlPlakkenTabel = "SELECT * FROM " & strTabel
        rsPlakkenTabel.Open sqlPlakkenTabel, conAccess, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

            Do Until rsCopierenTabel.EOF

                rsPlakkenTabel.AddNew

                    For i = 0 To rsCopierenTabel.Fields.Count - 1

                       rsPlakkenTabel.Fields(i) = rsCopierenTabel.Fields(i)

                    Next i

                    rsPlakkenTabel.Update

            rsCopierenTabel.MoveNext
            Loop

        rsPlakkenTabel.Close
        Set rsPlakkenTabel = Nothing

    End If

    rsCopierenTabel.Close
    Set rsCopierenTabel = Nothing
```

But this is for vb6 and now I am using VB.Net.
Isn't there an easy way to do this?
I have looked into datasets which have a link to the connection, but always to the same connection as in which they were filled.

Could somebody point me to the right way?
I don't want to loop the columns as I don't know the names of the columns.
(that is why fields(i) are so easy)

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the source tables in a `DataSet`, that would hold the 9 `DataTable` objects.  The rows in those `DataTable` objects would all have a [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Unchanged`.  Loop the rows in each `DataTable` and use the [`SetAdded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.setadded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on each row.

Once the rows are in an `Added` row state you can use the following code block to save them to your DB:

```
Private Sub UpdateAddedRows(MyDbAdapter As DbDataAdapter, dt As DataTable)
  Dim AddedRows As DataRow() = dt.[Select](Nothing, Nothing, DataViewRowState.Added)
  If AddedRows.Length > 0 Then
    Dim InsertCommand As DbCommand = NewDbCommand()
    Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO " & Convert.ToString(dt.TableName) & " ("
    Dim Vals As String = ""
    Dim dc As List(Of String) = ColumnList(dt)
    For dcInx As Integer = 0 To dc.Count - 1
        Dim p As DbParameter = DataColumnParameter(dt.Columns(dc(dcInx)))
        InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(p)
        If dcInx > 0 Then
            SQL += ", "
            Vals += ", "
        End If
        SQL += dc(dcInx)
        Vals += ParamNameDecorated(p.ParameterName)
    Next
    SQL += ") VALUES (" & Vals & ")"

    InsertCommand.CommandText = SQL
    MyDbAdapter.InsertCommand = InsertCommand
    MyDbAdapter.Update(AddedRows)
  End If
End Sub
```

This code block can be called to read one of the source tables:

```
Private Function GetData(ByRef ds As DataSet, TableName As String, SQL As String, pst As Boolean) As DataSet
  Dim MyDbAdapter As DbDataAdapter = NewDbDataAdapter()
  Dim MyDbCommand As DbCommand = NewDbCommand()
  MyDbCommand.CommandText = SQL

  If ds Is Nothing Then
    ds = New DataSet()
  End If
  If ds.Tables.Contains(TableName) Then
    ds.Tables.Remove(TableName)
  End If
  Dim dt As New DataTable(TableName)
  ds.Tables.Add(dt)

  MyDbAdapter.SelectCommand = MyDbCommand
  MyDbAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey

  Try
    MyDbAdapter.Fill(ds, TableName)
  Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print("Exception getting data. " + ex.Message)
    Throw
  End Try
  Return ds
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a datatable of the original database table but didn't change the rowstate so the table didn't get updated when I save it into the new database. Now I know why.